# LightInject Registration of Generic Query Handler

Tags: generics, dependencies, registration, code-injection

I am pretty new to the CQRS pattern and am having issues tying all of this together with my dependency injection container of choice.(LightInject)

What I have is a generic query object

```
public interface IQuery<TResult>
{
}
```

which is implemented by the GenericQuery

```
public class GenericQuery<TSrcEntity> : IQuery<IEnumerable<TSrcEntity>>
{
    public Expression<Func<TSrcEntity, bool>> Filter { get; set; }
    public Func<IQueryable<TSrcEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TSrcEntity>> OrderBy { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> IncludeProperties { get; set; }
}
```

I then handle all of this by way of a Query Dispatcher, which determines which handler to use through the dependency resolver

```
public class QueryDispatcher:IQueryDispatcher
{

    public TResult Dispatch<TQuery, TResult>(TQuery query) where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
    {
        var handler = DependencyResolver.Get<IQueryHandler<TQuery,TResult>>();
        return handler.Retreive(query);
    }
}
```

the Handler Implementation

```
 public class GenericQueryHandler<TSrcEntity> : IQueryHandler<GenericQuery<TSrcEntity>, IEnumerable<TSrcEntity>> where TSrcEntity : class
{
    public IEnumerable<TSrcEntity> Retreive(GenericQuery<TSrcEntity> query)
    {
        return GetDocuments();
    }
```

My registration for LightInject looks like this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new ServiceContainer();

        //service
        container.Register<ITestService, TestService>();

        //query
        container.Register(typeof(IQuery<>), typeof(GenericQuery<>));

        //handler This one works, but I dont want to register everything explicity.
        container.Register(typeof(IQueryHandler<GenericQuery<Document>, IEnumerable<Document>>), typeof(GenericQueryHandler<Document>));

        //dispatcher
        container.Register<IQueryDispatcher, QueryDispatcher>();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(container);

        var service = container.GetInstance<ITestService>();

        var a = service.GetDocuments();

    }
```

Everything is smooth as long as I explicitly register my handler as seen here

```
//handler This one works, but I dont want to register everything explicity.
        container.Register(typeof(IQueryHandler<GenericQuery<Document>, IEnumerable<Document>>), typeof(GenericQueryHandler<Document>));
```

But I don't want to do this for each entity. Can someone who is more familiar with LightInject help?

A sample program can be found at  [Generic Query Problem](https://github.com/levia7han/CQRS-Generic-Query/)

Thanks

Comment: Assuming that LINQ by itself provides enough abstraction for any filter-map-reduce needs, your additional abstraction seems as unneeded complexity to me. In addition, I would remove any CQRS reference in yous question since it is purely about registration of generics in your container.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. I have changed the post a bit. You are right it is more about registering the generic than CQRS.

Comment: @SimonFine Have you found a solution for this? I'm facing the exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I found a solution. I found the solution here: https://github.com/seesharper/LightInject/issues/350

The code on that page is this:

```
public static class ContainerExtensions
{
    public static void RegisterCommandHandlers(this IServiceRegistry serviceRegistry)
    {
        var commandTypes =
            Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()
                .GetTypes()
                .Select(t => GetGenericInterface(t, typeof(ICommandHandler<>)))
                .Where(m => m != null);
        RegisterHandlers(serviceRegistry, commandTypes);
        serviceRegistry.Register<ICommandExecutor>(factory => new CommandExecutor((IServiceFactory)serviceRegistry));            
        serviceRegistry.Decorate(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), typeof(TransactionalCommandDecorator<>));
    }


    public static void RegisterQueryHandlers(this IServiceRegistry serviceRegistry)
    {
        var commandTypes =
            Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()
                .GetTypes()
                .Select(t => GetGenericInterface(t, typeof(IQueryHandler<,>)))
                .Where(m => m != null);
        RegisterHandlers(serviceRegistry, commandTypes);
        serviceRegistry.Register<IQueryExecutor>(factory => new QueryExecutor((IServiceFactory)serviceRegistry));
        serviceRegistry.Decorate(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>), typeof(QueryHandlerLogDecorator<,>));
    }

    private static Tuple<Type, Type> GetGenericInterface(Type type, Type genericTypeDefinition)
    {           
        var closedGenericInterface = 
            type.GetInterfaces()
                .SingleOrDefault(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericTypeDefinition);
        if (closedGenericInterface != null)
        {
            var constructor = type.GetConstructors().FirstOrDefault();
            if (constructor != null)
            {
                var isDecorator = constructor.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).Contains(closedGenericInterface);
                if (!isDecorator)
                {
                    return Tuple.Create(closedGenericInterface, type);
                }
            }                
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static void RegisterHandlers(IServiceRegistry registry,  IEnumerable<Tuple<Type, Type>> handlers)
    {
        foreach (var handler in handlers)
        {
            registry.Register(handler.Item1, handler.Item2);
        }            
    }        
}
```